# Trying to understand how to work with IFS

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to understand how to work with the shell variable `IFS`. I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

ourpath=$PATH
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=":"
echo "ourpath = $ourpath"
for directory in "$ourpath"; do
    echo "directory = $directory"
done

IFS=$oldIFS
```

Running this using `bash test.sh` yields:

```
ourpath = ~/bin:/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin:/home/<user>/.local/bin:/home/<user>/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:~/scripts
directory = ~/bin:/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin:/home/<user>/.local/bin:/home/<user>/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:~/scripts
```

But I would expect `directory` to loop over the directories in `$PATH` because it should be split by `:`. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the exact same as with space: You have quoted `$ourpath` and it doesn't get split. If you remove the quotes then it will give you the result you're looking for.

I.e:

```
for directory in $ourpath ; do
    echo "directory = $directory"
done
```

Bonus points: It won't matter if `$ourpath` contains spaces because `IFS` is `:`, so it will only be split over `:`

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I got this (simplified) example from "Wicked Cool Shell Scripts: 101 Scripts for Linux, OS X, and UNIX Systems" by Dave Taylor and Brandon Perry (page 11), where they also quote `ourpath`. I wonder if that is a mistake on their behave or if I'm doing something else wrong.